# How can I optimize these Postgres queries and DB performance?

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I need some help in optimizing the following two queries which are almost similar but data selection is a little different. Here is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE public.rates (
  rate_id          bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  prefix           varchar(50),
  rate_name        varchar(30),
  rate             numeric(8,6),
  intrastate_cost  numeric(8,6),
  interstate_cost  numeric(8,6),
  status           char(3) DEFAULT 'act'::bpchar,
  min_duration     integer,
  call_increment   integer,
  connection_cost  numeric(8,6),
  rate_type        varchar(3) DEFAULT 'lcr'::character varying,
  owner_type       varchar(10),
  start_date       timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  end_date         timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  rev              integer,
  ratecard_id      integer,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT rates_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );
```

and two queries here I am using,

```
SELECT
    rates.* ,
    rc.ratecard_prefix ,
    rc.default_lrn ,
    rc.lrn_lookup_method ,
    customers.customer_id ,
    customers.balance ,
    customers.channels AS customer_channels ,
    customers.cps      AS customer_cps ,
    customers.balance  AS customer_balance 
FROM
    rates 
        JOIN ratecards rc 
        ON rc.card_type = 'customer' AND
        rc.ratecard_id = rates.ratecard_id 
        JOIN customers 
        ON rc.customer_id = customers.customer_id 
WHERE
    customers.status = 'act' AND
    rc.status = 'act' AND
    rc.customer_id = 'AB8KA191' AND
    owner_type = 'customer' AND
    '17606109973' LIKE concat (rc.ratecard_prefix, rates.prefix, '%') AND
    rates.status = 'act' AND
    now() BETWEEN rates. start_date AND
    rates.end_date AND
    customers.balance > 0 
ORDER BY
    LENGTH(PREFIX) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and the second one,

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    rates 
        JOIN ratecards rc 
        ON rc.card_type = 'carrier' AND
        rc.ratecard_id = rates.ratecard_id 
        JOIN carriers 
        ON rc.carrier_id = carriers.carrier_id 
        JOIN carrier_switches cswitch 
        ON carriers.carrier_id = cswitch.carrier_id 
WHERE
    rates.intrastate_cost < 0.011648 AND
    owner_type = 'carrier' AND
    '16093960411' LIKE concat (rates.prefix, '%') AND
    rates.status = 'act' AND
    carriers.status = 'act' AND
    now() BETWEEN rates.start_date AND
    rates.end_date AND
    rates.intrastate_cost <> -1 AND
    cswitch.enabled = 't' AND
    rates.rate_type = 'lrn' AND
    rates.min_duration >= 6 
ORDER BY
    rates.intrastate_cost ASC,
    LENGTH(rates.prefix) DESC,
    cswitch.priority DESC
```

I created an index on field `owner_type` (not shown in schema above) but the query performance is not really what is expected. CPU usage becomes too high for the DB server and everything starts to slow down. Explain output for first query is [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/s2Y) and the second one is [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/vk9m). 
When the number of records are less in the table, things work fine, naturally, but when the number of records increases the CPU goes higher. I currently have around 341821 records in the table.

How can I improve the query execution or possibly change the query in order to speed things up?

I have set `enable_bitmapscan = off` because I think this gives me better performance. If set to on, every index scan is followed up with a Bitmap heap scan.

Things did ease up a little bit by changing the query to

```
SELECT
    rates.*,
    rc.ratecard_prefix,
    rc.default_lrn,
    rc.lrn_lookup_method,
    customers.customer_id,
    customers.balance,
    customers.channels AS customer_channels,
    customers.cps      AS customer_cps,
    customers.balance  AS customer_balance 
FROM
    rates 
        JOIN ratecards rc 
        ON rc.card_type = 'customer' AND
        rc.ratecard_id = rates.ratecard_id 
        JOIN customers 
        ON rc.customer_id = customers.customer_id 
WHERE
    customers.status = 'act' AND
    rc.status = 'act' AND
    rc.customer_id = 'AB8KA191' AND
    owner_type = 'customer' AND
    (CONCAT (rc.ratecard_prefix, rates.prefix) IN ('16026813306',
    '1602681330',
    '160268133',
    '16026813',
    '1602681',
    '160268',
    '16026',
    '1602',
    '160',
    '16',
    '1')) AND
    rates.status = 'act' AND
    now() BETWEEN rates.start_date AND
    rates.end_date AND
    customers.balance > 0 
ORDER BY
    LENGTH(PREFIX) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Postgres.conf is [here](https://gist.github.com/nbhatti/bde441f3846f66bb832d)

But still each Postgres process takes around 25%+ CPU. I now also using pgbouncer to utilize connection pooling but still not helping.

Comment: "*query performance is not really what is expected*". The first query executes in 209ms, the second one in 116ms. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: Yes this is what happens when no other queries are running, but as soon as 40 or more parallel queries run, the CPU usage goes upto 100%, that is where the performance goes down steep. Just wanted to be sure what I am doing currently above is correct and if there is any room for improvement.

Comment: Your biggest contributor to the runtime (of the first query) is the hash join which is done in-memory, so that **is** going to CPU intensive. How many CPUs does your server have?

Comment: That's a dev machine with 4 cores assigned running over Parallels Desktop. Increasing the cores up to 8 does the same thing.

Comment: 8 cores vs. 40 (or more!) CPU intensive queries - each query uses one core. Are the runtimes we see for an execution under load or when nothing else is going on?

Comment: Runtimes are without anything else running.

Comment: `'17606109973' LIKE concat (rc.ratecard_prefix, rates.prefix, '%')` ... you must hate computers very much ...

Comment: The queries are giving fine output on an IDLE system, but under concurrent connections, 25 connections CPU peaks up to 100% each core. Is there a way we can figure out what's going on and why the CPU goes much higher?